# Error while building/deploying project in Qt creator

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

i'am workking with `Qt creator` in `Ubuntu 14.04` , 
my problem is : when i run my project , show me this :

```
Error while building/deploying project untitled3 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You've tagged this as Qt 4, but the error message clearly says Qt 5.7. Which is it?

Comment: can you show all the build output?